# Which symmetric key algorithm does SSL use?

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, cryptography, rsa

I understand that thru SSL, the browser gets public key of the secured website and thru public key encryption rsa algorithm, these 2 establish session key and then continue communication thru some symmetric algorithm, because symmetric key encryption/decryption is faster. Which symmetric key algorithm does SSL use? DES? AES? or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several, including those you mentioned - RC4 is common, AES is also available.

See [CipherSuite on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CipherSuite#Examples_of_algorithms_used) and also [Comparison of TLS implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_Implementations#Encryption_Algorithms). If you open up the security view for a page in your browser, it will show what encryption is being used for that page.

Answer (score 1):

Read the notes at the bottom of the wikipedia article for symmetric_key_algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_key_algorithm

It gives you a nice break down of the ciphers and how common they are.

My original answer (below) dealt with creating a private key.
OpenSSL uses three different cipher options to encrypt a private key:

1. DES
2. triple DES
3. IDEA

Read more about this at the openssl website:  http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/genrsa.html

Comment: OP's question is talking about the encryption after the session is set up, rather than encrypting the keys themselves.

Comment: Oops.  Got caught up in the section of the question about the rsa algorithm.